# Is it possible to interact with multiple contracts in the same .sol file using Truffle?

Tags: truffle, testrpc

Instead of separating each contract into it's own file, I'm wondering if/how I can interact with each individual contract one in a single `.sol` file through `truffle console`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

truffle console will automatically load all contracts regardless of their organization into .sol files. However, if you want to reference them in tests, just do

`contract = artifacts.require('MyContract')`

Without the .sol.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in adding this as an answer for you..